# R select certain values from multiple columns using conditions

Tags: r

I want to select certain values from multiple columns using conditions.(also let assign row 1 as ID#1, ... row5 as ID#5)

```
column1 <- c("rice 2", "apple 4", "melon 6", "blueberry 4", "orange 6")
column2 <- c("rice 8", "blueberry 8", "grape 10", "water 10", "mango 3")
column3 <- c("rice 6", "apple 8", "blueberry 12", "pineapple 8", "mango 3")
```

I want to get new column using IDs with condition only rice > 5, blueberry > 7 or orange > 5

First, I would like to get ID#1, ID#2, ID#3, ID#5

Second, I would to count how many conditions met per ID 
I would like to get results

```
ID#1 -> 2 conditions met
ID#2 -> 1 conditions met
ID#3 -> 1 conditions met
ID#4 -> 0 conditions met
ID#5 -> 1 conditions met
```

Comment: The columns don't have the same length?  It is also not clear about the conditions

Comment: Putting aside the issue of `column3` not having 5 values, I think you need to rearrange your data a bit first. Trying to work with values like `"rice 2"` `"group value"` won't allow you to do simple comparisons. I'd try splitting the number into a separate column if you can.

Comment: Hi @akrun all the columns do have the same length. Basically, I want to extract data which met criteria inside columns by IDs. I apologize for errors. all columns have the same length

Comment: @thelatemail How about I separate the values to 2 different columns. column1 has all name and column2 has all values. Please help me. Thanks a millions

Comment: `"rice 2"` is a single string, not two columns.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly then one of the approach could be

```r
library(dplyr)

cols <- names(df)[-1]

df1 <- df %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  mutate(rice_gt_5 = (select(., one_of(cols)) %>% 
                        rowwise() %>%
                        mutate_all(funs(strsplit(., split=" ")[[1]][1] =='rice' & as.numeric(strsplit(., split=" ")[[1]][2]) > 5)) %>%
                        rowSums)) %>%
  mutate(blueberry_gt_7 = (select(., one_of(cols)) %>% 
                        rowwise() %>%
                        mutate_all(funs(strsplit(., split=" ")[[1]][1] =='blueberry' & as.numeric(strsplit(., split=" ")[[1]][2]) > 7)) %>%
                        rowSums)) %>%
  mutate(orange_gt_5 = (select(., one_of(cols)) %>% 
                        rowwise() %>%
                        mutate_all(funs(strsplit(., split=" ")[[1]][1] =='orange' & as.numeric(strsplit(., split=" ")[[1]][2]) > 5)) %>%
                        rowSums))

#IDs which satisfy at least one of your conditions i.e. rice > 5 OR blueberry > 7 OR orange > 5
df1$ID[which(df1 %>% select(rice_gt_5, blueberry_gt_7, orange_gt_5) %>% rowSums() >0)]
#[1] 1 2 3 5

#How many conditions are met per ID
df1 %>%
  mutate(no_of_cond_met = rowSums(select(., one_of(c("rice_gt_5", "blueberry_gt_7", "orange_gt_5"))))) %>%
  select(ID, no_of_cond_met)
#  ID no_of_cond_met
#1  1              2
#2  2              1
#3  3              1
#4  4              0
#5  5              1
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, column1 = structure(c(5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
4L), .Label = c("apple 4", "blueberry 4", "melon 6", "orange 6", 
"rice 2"), class = "factor"), column2 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 2L, 
5L, 3L), .Label = c("blueberry 8", "grape 10", "mango 3", "rice 8", 
"water 10"), class = "factor"), column3 = structure(c(5L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("apple 8", "blueberry 12", "mango 3", 
"pineapple 8", "rice 6"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"column1", "column2", "column3"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: sorry. Let me try this solution and will let you know

Comment: not sure what happened I got this message Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: Evaluation error: non-character argument..

Comment: can you share `dput(head(df))`?